# Oracle LPAD() function

Tags: oracle

Question: For every part description that begins with the letter “b”, list the part description, and then pad each part description with a “+”on the left side so that all these part descriptions are 15 characters in length.

And I wrote like

```
  SELECT 
   LENGTH(PART_PART_DESCRIPTION),  LPAD(PART_PART_DESCRIPTION,15,'+'),
   PART_PART_DESCRIPTION, CONCAT('+', PART_PART_DESCRIPTION) FROM PART
   WHERE SUBSTR(PART_PART_DESCRIPTION,1,1)='B'
```

but the output doesn't show 15 of '+' on left side.

[Here is the output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gga7p.png)

Comment: LENGTH, LPAD, CONCAT and SUBSTR are not part of standard SQL. So please [edit] your question and indicate which database you are using. Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: I think it should be oracle

Comment: What is data type of `PART_PART_DESCRIPTION`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column `PART_PART_DESCRIPTION` is of `CHAR` data type with 285 data length. so `BLENDER` in your column has a total `285` (`7 + 278 trailing spaces`) length. that is why you are facing the problem.

See this:

```
SQL> select LPAD(CAST('BLENDER' AS CHAR(285)),15,'+') FROM DUAL;

LPAD(CAST('BLENDER'ASCHAR(285)),15,'+')
------------------------------------------------------------
BLENDER

SQL> select LPAD('BLENDER',15,'+') FROM DUAL;

LPAD('BLENDER',
---------------
++++++++BLENDER

SQL>
```

You need to use `TRIM` to properly use the `LPAD` on `CHAR` datatype column Something like the following:

```
LPAD(trim(PART_PART_DESCRIPTION),15,'+')
```

Comment: I think you need to mention that values in database table columns whose data type is CHAR are always padded with trailing spaces. Hence the value BLENDER in a column whose data type is CHAR(285) will have 278 trailing spaces.

Comment: Perfect @Abra !!

Comment: How can I get the length of the String? I don't why it shows the length is 285, Isn't it supposed to be the length of the size? I thought the "Length of basketball is 10"

Comment: Nope. It is `CHAR` data type. and for this data type, space is padded to the data. You must use `TRIM` or you must use `VARCHAR2` for storing strings in DB

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your data is padded with spaces. Try this

```
 SELECT 
   LENGTH(PART_PART_DESCRIPTION),  LPAD(TRIM(PART_PART_DESCRIPTION),15,'+'),
   PART_PART_DESCRIPTION, CONCAT('+', PART_PART_DESCRIPTION) FROM PART
   WHERE SUBSTR(PART_PART_DESCRIPTION,1,1)='B'
```